# Why is the ruby `require` not more fine-grained?

Tags: python, ruby, node.js

## Illustrative example

In the file b.rb I have the following two classes: Dog and Cat.

In ruby, to use the class Dog defined in the file b.rb, I have to require b.rb:

```
require 'b'

puts Dog.new.bark
```

But even though I don't need to have Cat, it is defined because all the classes in the required files have been loaded.

## The question

So my question is: Why isn't there in Ruby a way to require only parts of a file?

Is there a reason why it was not deemed necessary in Ruby, or is it included in some roadmap for the future of the language?

In python they have the `from module import MyClass` form, which lets the *importing file* choose what to import, and in the NodeJS world they have `module.export`, which lets the *imported file* choose what to export.

It would seem to me that Python and NodeJS are much more flexible in that aspect. What are the tradeoffs in ruby's choice?

Additional question: how is the python/nodeJS mechanism called (*selective importing*?)?

Comment: That is how `require` works in Ruby.

Personally, I would just put class `Dog` in dog.rb, and `Cat` in cat.rb. This is highly intuitive and encourages files from not turning messy.

Comment: I would argue that having multiple classes in one file is most of the time a bad practice - or at least not following common Ruby conventions.

Comment: It's just a different philosophy. Python packages tend to have few scripts, with many classes inside. Ruby gems tend to have many scripts, with at most one class per script. Python is a bit less dynamic and more explicit than Ruby, so it's easier for text editors and IDEs to analyze Python code. It's easier to jump around classes definitions in Python, wherever they are defined. With Ruby, there can be so many dynamic classes and methods definition that a text editor needs to know the underlying convention.

Answer (score 3):

That's just how `require` works: `require` runs the file. That's it. It doesn't do anything more than that.

If you want to add a module system to Ruby, that would be a massive change to how Ruby works.

Just don't define unrelated classes in the same file.

Comment: *"require runs the file. That's it. It doesn't do anything more than that."* -- Not **quite** true. The rarely-used `load` runs the file blindly; `require` only runs the file if it hasn't been run already.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the behaviour of Ruby's `require` is analogous to C's `include` (and MRI is written in `C`). So if we're talking about "why does ruby behave like this?", then one possible answer here is that it mimics the language it's written in.

Comment: No, `require` is *not* analogous to `#include`. `require` runs the file. `#include` lexically substitutes the contents of the file in place of the `#include` directive. That is completely and utterly different. For example, an `#include`d file doesn't even need to be syntactically valid. You could `#include` one file which contains the beginning of a statement and another file which contains the end of that statement. Or you can `#include` a subexpression into the middle of a larger function.

Comment: I did say **"analogous"**, and not "equivalent"... You are absolutely right about this crucial difference in implementation, but in normal usage the behaviour appears quite similar. Assuming you're not doing anything bizarre (e.g. `#include`-ing syntactically invalid files).

Comment: @JörgWMittag If *require* works like that, it begs the question *why* it was chosen to make it work like that, in contrast to Python's and NodeJS's way.

Comment: @NicolasWebDev: why not, that's why :) So far it works out just fine.

Comment: @NicolasWebDev: Designing a good module system is really, really hard, and in fact still an open research question. Ruby tends to rely on features that are tried and proven. If you look at all the powerful module systems in existence, e.g. Scala's, Newspeak's (both of which marry OO and modules beautifully), Racket's, and O'Caml's, then most of those are actually younger than Ruby. Since retro-actively bolting a module system onto a language (and an existing eco-system!) is hard (see Java 9 for an example), and powerful OO-module systems didn't yet exist when Ruby was designed, Ruby was …

Comment: … designed without one, and nobody has designed one since. If you want to, you are free to propose a design on the Ruby mailinglists or file a Feature Request on the Ruby Issue Tracker, and see whether it gets adopted. (Note: your chance will be much improved, if you provide detailed use cases, an implementation, and test cases.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Jörgs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232492/676874): You may take a loke on modules in ruby.

An example. Your `b.rb` looks like:

```
module Cats
  class Cat
    def meouw
      puts 'meouw'
    end
  end

end

module Dogs
  class Dog
    def bark
      puts 'wuff wuff'
    end
  end
end
```

Your script looks like:

```
require_relative 'b'

include Dogs
puts Dogs::Dog.new.bark #->wuff wuff
puts Dog.new.bark #->wuff wuff

puts Cats::Cat.new.meouw  #-> meouw
puts Cat.new.meouw  #-> Exception uninitialized constant Cat (NameError)
```

What happens in detail:

```
require_relative 'b'
```

You read the file. This executes everything in the file `b.rb` (it defines the classes).

```
include Dogs
```

No you load the Module `Dogs` into the actual scope. The class `Dog` is now available.

```
puts Dogs::Dog.new.bark #->wuff wuff
puts Dog.new.bark #->wuff wuff
```

You can use the class `Dog` in the scope of the module `Dogs` or you can use it direct.

```
puts Cats::Cat.new.meouw  #-> meouw
```

You also loaded the class `Cats::Cat` and you can use it.

```
puts Cat.new.meouw  #-> Exception uninitialized constant Cat (NameError)
```

The class `Cat` is not in the global scope (you never made a `import Cats`), so you get an exception.

And a last warning: The definition of `b.rb` is bad coding. Normally you create a `dog.rb` and a `cat.rb`. The you can require the classes independent.